# Do I have to annotate class when using CDI Events @Observes?

Tags: events, cdi

I create a class to observe an event.

Do I NEED to annotate this class with @Singleton? Or @Startup to force it listening when the application is up?

Or is it just enough to create a class, annotate the method with @Observes and it is done?

Comment: Did you **try**?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work. But I keep thinking about what could happen in unforeseen scenarios. So, what is the recommendation? That's the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the specs in chapter [10.3. Observer resolution](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#observer_resolution) it is defined:

> An event is delivered to an observer method if:
>   - The observer method belongs to an enabled bean. [...]

So what is a bean, according to the spec [3.1.1. Which Java classes are managed beans?](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#what_classes_are_beans):

> A Java class is a managed bean if it meets all of the following conditions:
>   - It is not an inner class.
>   - It is a non-abstract class, or is annotated @Decorator.
>   - It does not implement javax.enterprise.inject.spi.Extension.
>   - It is not annotated @Vetoed or in a package annotated @Vetoed.
>   - It has an appropriate constructor - either:
>           the class has a constructor with no parameters, or
>           the class declares a constructor annotated @Inject.

If your class meets this conditions and you have set the `bean-discovery-mode` in your beans.xml to "all", you don't need to annotate your class. If the `bean-discovery-mode` is set to annotated, your class must have at least the `@Dependent` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all `@Startup` is an EJB annotation, not CDI. Likewise, `@Singleton` can be EJB annotation (there is CDI one as well, but behaves a tad bit differently than what you may expect).

With that said, let's move on to the real question.
The discovery of observer method mandates that it is present on a CDI bean. So you can refer to what is CDI bean and when is such a bean found. With a bit of reading in CDI spec you will find out that this depends on [`bean discovery mode`](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_archive). If you have mode `all`, where every class will be a candidate for a bean (`@Dependent` one if not annotated with other scope), your observers will be found and picked up.

However, you may choose to use bean discovery mode `annotated`, where only classes with so called [*bean defining annotations*](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#bean_defining_annotations) classify as beans. In such a case, if there is observer on a method with no bean defining annotation, it will not be detected.

In short, if you always use some scope on the class which has an observer, you are safe.